# Распараллеливание обработки комбинаций

Tags: многопоточность, распараллеливание, длинная-арифметика

Моя программа генерирует 27 512 614 111 (27,5 миллиардов) комбинаций чисел.
Кажется, что нереально страшная цифра, но всё не так. Программа в чистом виде делает это за 10 мин на одном ядре. Однако мне нужно производить некоторые вычисления с полученной комбинацией чисел, соответственно программа начинает резко притормаживать:

- Используется арифметика с плавающей запятой
- Добавляются несколько циклов для вычисления
- использование оператора **ЕСЛИ** на каждой итерации, вплоть до 27,5 миллиарда так же вставляет палки в колёса (сам убедился, что проверка условия сильно тормозит любую программу при больших вычисления)

Возможно ли распараллелить обработку комбинаций? У меня 8 ядер в процессоре. Как разбить все комбинации по 27,5 / 8 = 3.4 миллиарда комбинаций. Это очень ускорит работу, но я не понимаю как для каждой функции, запускаемой в поток, отделить мои комбинации.
Комбинации по 7 элементов, туда входят число от 0 до 30

- 0 0 0 0 0 0
- ...
- 0 31 0 31 31 31 0

и т.д.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: например, `n`-ый поток может обрабатывать комбинации, первая цифра в которых принадлежит отрезку `[n*4, n*4 + 1]` (нулевой поток — комбинации начинающиеся с 0,1,2 или 3; первый поток — с 4,5,6 или 7 и т. д.

Comment: В ваших вычислениях над одной комбинацией  участвует только она или и какие-то другие комбинации или результаты вычислений над ними? Если хотите конкретных советов, то опишите принципиальные алгоритмы этих вычислений.

Comment: Несложные числовые алгоритмы с гигантским, но предсказуемым и хорошо делящимся количеством итераций можно реализовать для GPU и тем повысить скорость обработки в разы. В современных видеокартах ядер на порядок больше.

Comment: Участвует только что полученная новая комбинация и над ней производится немножко вычислений. Далее это вычисление никак не касается других комбинаций

Comment: Для C/C++ можно задействовать [OpenMP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) для "обычного" распараллеливания, без погружения в детали его реализации.

Comment: На Visual Studio есть такая библиотека ?

Comment: Можете ли вы быстро сказать какой будет комбинация под номером 0x400127? Если да - каждый поток должен получать свой номер N(0-7), стартовая комбинация для них - 3.4*10^9*N, конечная - 3.4*10^9*(N+1). Так это и делается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение проблемы. Если вы перебираете размещения с повторениями, то возьмите счётчик, который считает от 0 до 2 млрд (__int64 подойдет для этих целей), далее останавливаете цикл, когда дойдет до 2 млрд и смотрите на состав элементов последовательности. 
Если у вас начальные элементы это все нули, а на 2 млрд, к примеру 
9 8 1 2 7 1 8, то запомните этот состав, и далее начните перебор, задав начальной последовательностью не нули, а вышеуказанной, и опять считаете 2 млрд и т.д.! Это очень простое решение в лоб! Спасибо всем кто участвовал